# Convert Angular/NodeJS HTTPS client to Spring Boot application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, spring-boot

I have an UI application built on Angular/NodeJS which is HTTPS enabled. We are working on a POC and want to convert it to java micro-service on Spring Boot.

I have built the Node project and used the dist folder with Spring Boot project which is working fine.

The issue I'm facing is that Node was referring to pem certificates for HTTPS whereas with Spring Boot app I'm using keystone.

When dist folder used with Spring Boot, will it automatically use java keystore for establishing a connection with other micro-service or do I need to provide path to pem certificates?

I don't have much experience with NodeJS.

Comment: What is the exact problem ?

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati How can I use jks rather than pem. Will it require any code change on Node side?

Comment: But this task is to migrate node to spring boot, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. Node application calls other services over https protocol. It uses pem certificates. Now using Node build with Spring Boot, how this service calling part will be handled in Spring Boot?.

Comment: My Suggestion: Use Nginx to configure all the SSL part instead of doing from the application.